# Get hourly result for count in the last 48 hours - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that returns the count every hour for the last 48 hours.
Until now I tried either:

```
SELECT count(*), date_format(created, '%H:%i - %d/%m/%y') as datecreated
FROM mimesi_indexer.served_clips
where created > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
group by floor(hour(created))
order by created ASC
```

and:

```
SELECT count(*), date_format(created, '%H:%i - %d/%m/%y') as datecreated
FROM mimesi_indexer.served_clips
where created > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
group by floor(hour(created))
order by created ASC
```

But neither of those give the wanted result.
Do you have any idea on how I could do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every hour, don't you want this:

```
SELECT count(*), date_format(created, '%H - %d/%m/%y') as datecreated
FROM mimesi_indexer.served_clips
where created > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
group by date_format(created, '%H - %d/%m/%y')
order by min(created) ASC;
```

That is, you need to include the day as well as the hour -- and remove the minutes from `datecreated`.

Comment: I tried, it's not grouping them by hour but by minutes or so. Any idea on how to group them by hour perfectly?

Comment: Try `'%H:%i - %d/%m/%y'` to `'%H - %d/%m/%y'`